# Show floating action button depending on the URL

Tags: android, url, webview, show-hide, floating-action-button

this is my first question after reading and implementing some methods I've learned here... but I have a question:

I'm creating a webView, I would like to show a floating button only when I open images, I know that all the pictures have "fbcdn.net" in the url.

But I don't know how hide the button "Descarga" if the url does not contain "fbcdn.net"

Thank you for your answers.

this is my code:

```
final String webUrl1 = webView.getUrl();

    if(webUrl1.contains("fbcdn.net") ){
        descarga.show();

        descarga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(null, webUrl1);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to Clipboard!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
        descarga.hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming descarga is your FloatingActionButton, instead of using hide()/show() try using descarga.setVisibility(View.GONE) (for hiding the fab) and descarga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) (for showing the fab).